# How to display HTML file inside ASP.NET Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-helper, webforms

I have an embed device which is returning back info in HTML files,
Now I trying to make ASP.NET webform application, so end users can see these logs.
What is proper way to open HTML file at local server and display inside webform.

Comment: have a look at this article, might help you http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/controlhtml/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are complete HTML files (including `<html>` and `<body>` tags) then it's probably best to show them in a Frame. Are they in a location you can create an URL for?

For html fragments you'll have to load them in code-behind and show them in for example a Literal control.

Comment: Thanx on answer, They Are full HTML files with body and tags, And they are placed  at web server, I can make Virual-Direcory there

Answer (score 3):

you could use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(CONTENTSOFHTMLFILE)` and output it to a `label` or `literal` control

Answer (score 0):

in **aspx** file :

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="htmlLiteral" />
```

in cs file **Page_Load** method :

```
htmlLiteral.Text = "<h2>aaa</h2>";
```

Replace aaa h2 with your complete html string